# Responsive header /slideshow is not responsive - maybe caused by slideshow

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideshow, swiper.js

I have this header with a slideshow in it.

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PVbEK/1/

I would like the header (`.swiper-container`) to be responsive in height as in width. Right now the height remains the same when scaled up or down, but the content is responsive.

I would like the height to be proportionally scaled, like the content.

I think the slideshow is causing this issue, but I can't see where the error is?

I am using the Swiper slideshow: http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/api.php

I have tried flex slider, but I don't think the touch features is working that well on a windows phone

Can this be fixed with CSS?

Daniel

Comment: i've yet to see a slider which is responsive in both height and width of its images. Maybe someone can proove me wrong?

Comment: @Mysteryos You haven't seen a responsive slider or?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use padding top.

Eg. Your banner is 1000px by 400px

So the height would be 400/1000*100 = 40%

```
#banner{
    max-width:1000px;
    width:100%;
    padding-top:40%;
}
```

Let's say the banner was 800px by 350px

So this height would be 350/800*100 = 43.75%

```
    #banner{
        max-width:800px;
        width:100%;
        padding-top:43.75%;
    }
```

This article gives an in depth example

http://voormedia.com/blog/2012/11/responsive-background-images-with-fixed-or-fluid-aspect-ratios

Comment: can you show me how you would do this with my slider,

In the fiddle above?

Because, it is not working for me.